# Convert ogg/oga file to wav using Java

Tags: java, wav, ogg, oggvorbis

I [have an ogg](https://file.io/CJWFsXL6IgZa) file downloaded from whatsapp. I am trying to convert it to wav. However, reading the input stream is failing  with Unsupported format.

```
        File file = new File("audio.ogg");
        AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: File of unsupported format
        at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1066)
        at org.Convert.main(Convert.java:20)
```

I added following dependency to no avail.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>vorbisspi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you've got all necessary deps.  vorbis-java-core seems possible